# How to add custom horizontal and vertical scrolling in Angular 9?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have an angular app , in which a user uploads a file and then I show the contents of the file on the UI. The file might be very long, so I need vertical scrolling and also for longer lines, I would like to have horizontal scrolling. So I think I will need a box in which I'll show the content with horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Code for `app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  fileContent: string = '';

  public onChange(fileList: FileList): void {
    let file = fileList[0];
    let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    let self = this;
    fileReader.onloadend = function(x) {
      self.fileContent = fileReader.result;
    }
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

Code for `app.component.html`

```js
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event.target.files)">

<div>
  <h3>File Content</h3>
  <pre> {{fileContent}} </pre>
</div>
```

How can I add horizontal and vertical scrolling ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set max-height, max-width and overflow property in the div for file content. When the content are more than the given height, then scroll will appear automatically.

Comment: You can check this http://itakeitalltheway.blogspot.com/2010/07/scroll-on-when-reach-max-height-ie-and.html?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the element which you want to have the scroll, just add property `overflow: auto;`

In your case you might want to do that on your div, I would suggest adding a class and then apply property for it to overflow.

```
.myDiv {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

In case you want specific direction, you have `overflow-x: scroll;` and `overflow-y: scroll;`.